# Adding an option "Select all" to an EntityType Field returns the error "Unable to reverse value for property path"

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form with an EntityType Field which retrieve a list of hotels.

I would like to add to that list an option "Select all" to get directly a list of all the hotels.

I created an EntityTypeExtension (I prefer that to a custom extended type for now) with the following :

```
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $list = $this->em->getRepository($options['class'])->findAll();
    $new_choice = new ChoiceView($list, 'all', 'Select all'); // <- new option
    $view->vars['choices'][] = $new_choice;//<- adding the new option
}
```

This works, but if I select "Select all" I get the following stack :

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation

Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[hotel] = all

Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

Unable to reverse value for property path "[hotel]": The choice "all" does not exist or is not unique

Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException

The choice "all" does not exist or is not unique
```

I assume the DataTransformer does not recognize the "all" option.

Do you have any idea ? Should I overload the EntityType DataTransformer ?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to add `multiple => true` to your form type options to allow an array of ids to be transformed automatically(providing your entity has a collection of hotels) or you need to implement your own data transformer (wich is fairly simple).

In your case you would need a view transformer

Data transformer doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

I think that the value parameter of the ChoiceView constructor (second parameter) should be an array of the ids of the objects in `$list` as `EntityType` expects the value of choices to be an object id.